# File Name for custom helper

Tags: module, magento-1, helper

I am trying to replace the helper that provides the compare box with the list of products added to it. My helper is going to get the product ids from a cookie instead of from Magentos session.

As I understand things I need to create a file in `app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Helper/Data.php` and put my own class in this file. Is this correct or should I put the file somewhere else or perhaps give it a different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add the helper class detail in confif.xml file

...

```
<global>
    <helpers>
      <[modelname]>
        <class>[NameSpace]_[Modelname]_Helper</class>
      </[modelname]>
    </helpers>
<global>
```

....

Crete the data.php file in [NameSpace][Modelname]\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php
class [NameSpace]_[Modelname]_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the config.xml file? Am I correct in understanding that it should be placed in `app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/etc/`?

Comment: yes that file already there just you have to add <helper> tag in <global> tag

Comment: you welcome :) :)